# Swift3 SwiftSocket returning UnknownError when trying to connect to python TCP socket server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, swift3

I'm making a Swift iOS application for my phone. It needs to connect to a python socket server. The server works fine when I do telnet using terminal on my mac, but when ever I try to connect using the app, the app returns UnknownError. But when I put in, for example www.google.com and port 80 or when I do a device on the local network with a webpage, it works fine. Why isn't it connecting and how can I fix it?

Here is a link to the library that I used: https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket

Here is the code that is used on the device:

```
let host = "192.168.0.24"
let port = 250
var client: TCPClient?
client = TCPClient(address: host, port: Int32(port))

guard let client = client else { return }

            switch client.connect(timeout: 10) {
            case .success:
                appendToTextField(string: "Connected to host \(client.address)")
                if let response = sendRequest(string: "01", using: client) {
                    appendToTextField(string: "Response: \(response)")
                    ideaLabel.text = readResponse(from: client)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                appendToTextField(string: String(describing: error))
            }
```

Here is the server code:

```
import socket
import sqlite3
from random import randint

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 250)
print("Starting Server")
s.bind(server_address)
print("Waiting for client")
s.listen(1)
alive = True

while(alive == True):
    connection, client_address = s.accept()
    print(client_address)

    try:
        command = connection.recv(2)

        if (command == "01"):
           conn = sqlite3.connect('ideas.db')
           c = conn.cursor()
           file = open("maxID.txt", "r")
           maxID = (int(file.read()) + 1)
           ideaNumber = (randint(1,maxID),)
           c.execute('SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE id=?', ideaNumber)
           idea1 = c.fetchone()
           idea = str(idea1)
           conn.close()
           idea = idea.translate(None, "1234567890'(),u")
           #idea = idea.translate("u",".")
           print("Your idea is:")
           print(idea)
           connection.send(str(idea))

   finally:
       connection.close()
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @Zmart Yes I did, the issue was the server address on the server script was set to 'localhost', but it should've been left blank. Ill add a answer soon.